# LaTeX template for old-school style mathematics exposition (monographs with numbered paragraphs, etc...)

Tags: sectioning, templates

I'm wondering whether anyone has come across latex templates for formatting mathematics like it used to be written in older works by Weyl, Hertz, Maxwell, Ricci, and others.  You can see this kind of style in the Dover books.

Essentially, you have exposition running in numbered sections, but the sections aren't set off, or larger font.  They are just bold.  Typically, the section numbers are prefaced with the double-hooking ss, the kind that used to be used for footnotes as well (not the dagger).

Anything template or style that is reminiscent of the older styles would be much appreciated!

Comment: The sectioning used there could be `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` with custom numbering. So you could either use those or redefine `\section` to look like the `\paragraph`s.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks.  I ended up combining your suggestion about redefining `\section` and `\subsection`, etc., with a new command to define attractive numbered paragraphs with `§` prefixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst ideally I was hoping for an existing template style, following @moewe's suggestion in the comments, I ended up redefining `\section` and `subsection`etc., and also adding a new command to define attractive numbered paragraphs with`§` prefixed.

The code for this is below.  To use it, just prefix a paragraph with `\p`.

```
 \newcounter{parcount}
 \newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}
 \newcommand{\p}{                       %  use \p in front of a paragraph to number.
     \stepcounter{parcount}
     \vspace{4mm}                       %  a little vspace for aesthetics
     \noindent\S{\parnum}.\hspace{5mm}  %  prefix with § followed by a little hspace
    }
```